# SQL view takes long time to finish, but the same internal query executes in 1 second

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing a weird experience with a query which is for handling data from ADO. Here is the view

```
ALTER view [dbo].[v_Missing_Pepics] as

select ProjectName Title,PM.ProjectCode,LifeCycle,dbo.fn_kip_ado_status_mapping(LifeCycle,PM.ProjectCode) KipStatus,TeamCode,ISNULL((select top 1 value from string_split(TA.AreaPath,'\') where LTRIM(value) like 'Domain%'),'Automation') Domain,DM.DomainName KipDomain,TeamName
from [dbo].[v_ProjectMaster_Latest] PM
left outer join areapath_mapping TA on TA.KeyedInTeamCode=PM.TeamCode
left join v_portfolio_epics PE on PE.ProjectCode=PM.ProjectCode
inner join domain_master DM on DM.DomainCode=PM.DomainCode
where ProjectActive = 'yes'  and LifeCycle not in ('In Close-Down', 'Completed','Withdrawn') 
and PE.ProjectCode is null and DM.DomainName not in ('Data Power') and PM.ProjectCode not like 'EXP%'

GO
```

When I try to execute the query like this

```
Select * from v_Missing_Pepics
```

It took more than 80sec to finish. But when I copy the query alone (Within the view), it executes in just 1 second.

I don't understand why??

I am working in Azure SQL.

Comment: For performance help, we need to have the table and index definitions, and share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: referring views in another view causes more time to execute instead of using views inside view it is better to use nested query. If ```v_ProjectMaster_Latest``` or  ```v_portfolio_epics``` is view then it will take more time to execute as data size is increase

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sp_recompile 'v_Missing_Pepics'
```

And see if that resolves the performance problems with the view.

Comment: Actually I tried that, but doesnt give any difference.. :( Is that issue is for Azure SQL only??

Comment: I would run it and compare query plans.